# Propagate header for a feign method, inside an async call

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, interceptor

hope you are all doing well.

I have a RequestInterceptor, which captures my Authorization Header and propagates it forwarr:

```
@Component
public class FeignAuthHeaderInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        if (attributes != null) {
            HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
            String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (authHeader != null) {
                template.header("Authorization", authHeader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When calling a feign request from a local thread, I have no problem propagating the header. But when calling the method inside a CompletableFuture.runAsync(), the header is null.
Would you be so kind as to provide me with further details of why this doesn't work?

Thank you, in advance.